# Проблема с синтаксисом mysql UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Сейчас использую строку запроса `string str = "UPDATE InfoID SET " + pole + " = '" + data + @"' WHERE ID = " + id;`

```
string pole = "userFirstName";

string data = "Ариша";

int id=111;
```

> Проблема в том что data записывается как `?????`

Код метода

```
public static void UpdateBaceInfo(long id, string pole, string data)
        {
            string patch = Form1.PatcBaseA + "\\" + "Data_Application" + ".mdf";
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + patch + @"; Integrated Security=True";
            sqlConnectioninfo3 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            sqlConnectioninfo3.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(50);

            if (sqlConnectioninfo3 != null && sqlConnectioninfo3.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConnectioninfo3 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                sqlConnectioninfo3.Open();
            }
            string s = "UPDATE InfoID SET " + pole + "=[" + data + @"] WHERE ID = " + id;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(s, sqlConnectioninfo3);
            //записать значения
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlConnectioninfo3.Close();
        }
```

Comment: а вы в sql саначала запрос напишите и посмотрите в чем разница. Символьные значения в sql в кавычках например задаются. причем еще надо учитывать, что внутри самого значения то же могут быть кавычки и их надо экранировать.

Comment: А еще лучше - использовать параметризированные запросы

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста пример строки, если моя строка неверна

Comment: Покажите значение переменной sql ПОСЛЕ подстановки значений.

Comment: UPDATE InfoID SET userFirstName =[Ариша]  WHERE ID = 111

Comment: Должно быть: `UPDATE InfoID SET userFirstName = 'Ариша' WHERE ID = 111`